# How to over write helm values yaml file?

Tags: bash, kubernetes-helm, argocd

In my values file I have

```
image:
  tag: '123465'
```

I want to overwrite this from my github ci/cd so Argocd can pick it up

I'm writing this command

```
sed -i 's|image.tag:.*|image.tag: test|g' dev-*.yaml
```

I'm getting

> sed: 1: "dev.yaml": extra characters at the end of d command

error.

What am I missing?

Comment: I do something like `sed -i "s|${IMAGE}.*|${IMAGE}:${IMAGE_TAG}|g"`. if you are modifying yaml, you should look into `yq`

Answer (score 2):

Is it necessary for you to use `sed`? `helm` supports overriding values via the command line, so you can do something like:

```bash
helm install some-name some-chart --set "image.tag=test"
```

This will override the value from the `values.yaml` file with the value `test`.

Above is detailed out in the [documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/).

---

#### Using `sed`

The error message you've shared does not match the command, maybe it got mixed up?

Assuming you have a `dev.yaml` file with:

```yaml
image:
  tag: '123456'
```

You can replace the `tag` value with `foobar` using:

```bash
sed -i 's|^  tag:.*|  tag: "foobar"|' dev.yaml
```

Keep in mind that the two spaces before `tag` within the `sed` command are intentional.

This however breaks down rather quickly if you have another `tag:` somewhere in your file, say:

```yaml
image:
  tag: "123456"

someOtherImage:
  tag: "baz"
```

Running the above command will yield a file that has *both* `tag:` values replaced. To get around this, you can use branching:

```bash
sed -i '/^image:$/{ n; s|^  tag:.*$|  tag: "foobar"|g }' dev.yaml
```

Here, `/^image:$/` matches lines that contain exactly `image:`, `n;` directs `sed` to load the immediate next line, while the final `s|^  tag:.*$|  tag: "foobar"|g` `sed` command does the tag replacement, only for the line after `image:`.

Above is inspired from this [blog](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/find-matching-text-replace-next-line#1-twosed-one-liners).

Comment: In addition to `helm install --set`, also consider `helm install -f` to use an additional YAML values file overriding the chart's `values.yaml`.  It also may be relevant that syntactically valid JSON is also valid YAML; is your CI tool can write out JSON then it can be passed to `helm install -f`.